# SignalR .Net Client connection limit

Tags: c#, iis, signalr, windows-10-universal

I have .net client on Windows Universal App and SignalR Server hosted on localhost web api, IIS windows 10,

client app installed on windows 10, when one client connection started then seconds client connection Start method goes hang, and if I disconnected one client then seconds one able to connect, 
SignalR server have IIS Windows 10 table, Atom Processor.

So is there any connection limit for this and or configuration related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Created Self hosted SignalR sever console application,

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Join8POS.SignalRServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
            // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
            // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
            // for more information.
            string localComputerName = Dns.GetHostName();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter SignalR Server Host IP Address: ");
            IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress hostIP in localIPs)
            {
                // is localhost
                if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(hostIP))
                {

                }
                if (hostIP.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {

                }
                var ipp= hostIP.MapToIPv4();
            }
            var inp= Console.ReadLine();
            string url = "http://"+inp+":8080";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                outer:
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress 'C' to close SignalR server.");
                var ky= Console.ReadKey();
                if (ky.KeyChar != 'C')
                {
                    goto outer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            // UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(config);
            //WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            };
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the cors middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch is already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
    [HubName("shopApiHub")]
    public class ShopApiHub : Hub
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ShopApiHub OnConnected
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            //CustomLogging.Log("OnConnected  "+ Context.ConnectionId, LoggingType.SignalRShopHub);
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked on Take Out order generated.
        /// </summary>
        public void TakeOutOrderRaise()
        {
            Clients.All.takeOutOrderRaise();
            //CustomLogging.Log("TakeOutOrderRaise ", LoggingType.SignalRShopHub);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// invoked when got any update in runningtable.xml
        /// </summary>
        public void refreshFloorPlan()
        {
            Clients.All.refreshFloorPlan();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// OnDisconnected
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bl"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool bl)
        {
            return base.OnDisconnected(bl);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Allowed Inbound port 8080 in windows firewall.
        and signalr .net client able to connect in local network using IPv4 address. like (10.10.10.35)

[SignalR Server Self hosted application running on 10.10.10.35:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deOgb.png)